# Model threshold for classification model

Tags: machine-learning, python, classification, scikit-learn

How do I extract a model score based on desired precision recall for a classification model? Is there a command to extract it from `precision_recall` function in sklearn?

Comment: Welcome to the community, @user76804! Please consider adding some sample code to your question. It can further clarify your questions.

Answer (score 1):

```
p, r, thresholds = precision_recall_curve(y_test, y_scores)
```

For more clear understanding refer to this article:
https://towardsdatascience.com/fine-tuning-a-classifier-in-scikit-learn-66e048c21e65